# getting "Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component" error on react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**[enter code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdjNW.png)**

here is the code snapshot of login which I getting the error in. I cannot solve it as a new react user please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an *actual* [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a properly formatted and readable code snippet instead of an image of code. Images are not accessible, searchable or copy/pasteable, and can be more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

The `navigate` function should be called as an intentional side-effect, not in directly in the component body as an unintentional side-effect. Move that logic into an `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user || userGoogle) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  }
}, [navigate, user, userGoogle]);
```